# While importing XML to MS Access 2003, boolean variable is being imported as string

Tags: xml, ms-access, xml-import

I am trying to import an XML file into MS Access 2003, through File>Get External Data>Import. And I want to import a field as boolean. I have pre-built the tables and importing the data only. I am confused that what should be value of boolean in XML so that it can easily get imported as aceess boolean variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm I'd go with 0 for false and -1 for true. But I suspect it would also convert these pairs as well...

```
False Value   True Value 
  0            -1 
  0            {any non-zero integer} 
  False        True 
  No           Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about proper XML representation of various data types [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes).  For boolean, you can use "true" or "1" for true and "false" or "0" for false.  Note also the proper representation for date, time, and datetime.